# extract code which can be variable length from string

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following string,

```
string fileName = "mnb_CREDUV_151030.csv"
```

I am also given a string which is "mnb_CRED". What I need to do with the fileName is get the code bit, i.e "CREDUV". Its possible that its more than 2 characters extra than CRED. What is the best way to go about this?

I was going to use loop through each character in the file name and apply some logic. Wondering if there is a better way though?

Comment: You wanna get _always_ the text between first `_` and second `_` character? Do you have a pattern?

Comment: Split on the character '_'

Comment: there are actually 4 _ (not sure who comes up with these great names) but guess find the second and third and take the inbetween - is that what you are thinking?

Comment: `fileName.Split('_')[1]` should give you the part.

Comment: Regex is best for matching regular expressions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) to capture the contents between two underscores, or an underscore and the end of the string:

```
var regex=new Regex("_(?<code>[A-Za-z0-9]+)(_|$)");

var x=regex.Match("mnb_CRED_sdfsd.sdf");
var code=x.Groups["code"].Value;
Debug.Assert(x.Groups["code"].Value=="CRED");

var x2=regex.Match("mnb_CRED");
Console.WriteLine(x2.Groups["code"].Value);
```

`$` means the end of the string, so the pattern will capture text between the first and second underscore, or the end of the line.

The `(?<code>\w+)` pattern matches any non-whitespace character ( \w+ ) and applies the name `code` to it. This makes it easy to capture different parts of a pattern and access them using a name.

The nice thing about regular expressions is that they are a lot faster than string splitting and use much less memory, especially when processing a lot of strings. The reason is that matching doesn't generate temporary strings like splitting. A match or a group only contains a start and end index. A string is generated only when you use `Value` to get the captured text.

The downside is that regular expressions are yet another thing to learn, and obviously, they aren't the simplest of languages.

Comment: But the OP says he could also get just mnb_CRED

Comment: Which is why the pattern contains `$` - the end of string marker